# Doing http requests in linear fashion in Scala/Play

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am using play's `WSClient` to make REST calls. Each response is of type `Future[WSResponse]`. If I have a list of URLs and I make REST calls for all those URLs, I will get a collection of `Future[WSResponse]`. I understand the concept of `Future.sequence` and `Future.traverse`. But my requirement is slightly different.

I have say `List(url1, url2,url3)` I want to make the REST call to `url1`, once the Future[WSResponse] is complete, I want to make the call to `url2` and so on... How do I do that? I want to have a lambda to do something for each response as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty general example method:

```
def mapToFutureInSequence[A, B](as: List[A], f: A => Future[B])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[List[B]] = {
  as.foldLeft(Future.successful(List.empty[B])) { (fbs, a) =>
    for {
      bs <- fbs
      b <- f(a)
    } yield b :: bs
  }.map(_.reverse)
}
```

In this case, `A` would be a url and `f` would be `WSClient`'s method that returns a `Future[WSResponse]`, or some custom function combined with that if you want to involve the lambda you mentioned.